# Express application not responding to outside traffic

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, express, bower

I have a webservice (private-bower) that listen on port 5678 on a remote ubuntu machine.

netstats:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5678            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10605/node
```

I don't have any rules in my iptables and the ufw status is inactive.
I get a response by doing $curl ip:5678 only within my remote machine, but when I do it on my local one, I receive no response what so ever.

The remote ip is pingable from my local machine btw.

I didn't write that webservice, here's the line where it starts to listen:

```
var server = app.listen(_config.port, function() {
    logger.log('Bower server started on port ' + _config.port);
});
```

How can I let external ip address to make request on that port?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

app.listen by default listens on localhost, you can pass in a different bind address as the second argument as described in docs. as I understand it: `0.0.0.0` represents 'all available interfaces' and `localhost` represents 'only loopback interface'

```
var server = app.listen(_config.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    logger.log('Bower server started on port ' + _config.port);
});
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as well, to not only provide the OP with working code, but also teach him something.